# How to update several tables in one query? 

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to update multiple tables in one SQL statement.

I am trying to execute the query:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A, TABLE_B SET TABLE_A.FIELD_A = 0, TABLE_B.FIELD_B = 0;
```

But I am getting the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
```

What is wrong in my query?
I use `Oracle 11` if it is important.

Comment: Each data modification statement in SQL can affect *one* table only. You have to split your query into multiple `UPDATE`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot update multiple tables in single query.

You can write a stored procedure to update both tables. Have the two UPDATEs wrapped within a transaction.